# Do we have a memory in Django application?

Tags: python, django

What if I want to store a short data set in the memory of my application?
Do we have a memory in Django application or maybe it is better to ask if Django is alive?

I know that I can save queries in Redis but I want to know if there is a better and faster way to save data in one view and retrieve those from another view using memory?

Is it right or wrong at all?
Thanks

Update:

Let me explain my question again. In Django we will get user request and process it in view, then we return a response, I mean Django will be dead after returning the response and does not save any state in itself. I want to know if there is a way to have an application which stores states?

Comment: You're question is very  broad,  what are you trying to do? Django has the usual forms of data storages

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use the in process memory for even short term persistence in Django and other WSGI applications. In a production environment it is common to have the application spread to several processes or even machines. Shared key/value stores or databases are used instead.

Comment: @Sayse I am just curious if saving something in memory is useful and right to do? I have been using Redis to cache my queries until now.

Comment: It's not at all true that Django is "dead" after returning a response.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can you please explain a little more why it's not true?

Comment: Sounds like you want sessions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/